# How to count characters in a string? (python)

Tags: python, count

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-

str= "Green tree"
scr= "e"

cstr= len(str)
n=0
a=0

while n < cstr:
    if str[n] == scr:
        print(len(scr))
    n=n+1
```

I have to count "e" in -str- string, but when I run this script I get

```
1
1
1
1
```

instead of 4.

What's the problem?

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name. It shadows the builtin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, don't use `str` as a variable name, it will mask the built-in name.

As for counting characters in a string, just use the [`str.count()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method:

```
>>> s = "Green tree"
>>> s.count("e")
4
```

If you are just interested in understanding why your current code doesn't work, you are printing `1` four times because you will find four occurrences of 'e', and when an occurrence is found you are printing `len(scr)` which is always `1`.

Instead of printing `len(scr)` in your if block, you should be incrementing a counter that keeps track of the total number of occurrences found, it looks like you set up a variable `a` that you aren't using, so the smallest change to your code to get it to work would be the following (however as noted above, `str.count()` is a better approach):

```
str= "Green tree"
scr= "e"

cstr= len(str)
n=0
a=0

while n < cstr:
    if str[n] == scr:
        a+=1
    n=n+1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [count method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
>>> st="Green tree"
>>> st.count('e')
4
```

If the count method is broken on your Python ;-), you can use a for loop:

```
st="Green tree"
tgt='e'
i=0
for c in st:
    if c==tgt: i+=1

print i 
# 4
```

If you really want a while loop:

```
idx=0
i=0
while idx<len(st):
    if st[idx]==tgt: i+=1
    idx+=1

print i
```

But, this being Python, a more 'Pythonic' approach if your count method broken is to use `sum` on a generator expression:

```
>>> sum(1 for c in st if c=='e')
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scr= "e"
##
print(len(scr))
```

For *why* it's doing this, it's doing what you asked, and printing the length of the variable `scr`, which is always one.

You're best to use the `str.count()` method as others mentioned, or increment a counter yourself manually.