# Regex inside findall vs regex inside count

Tags: python, regex, pandas

This is a follow up question to [How to count characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724695/how-to-count-characters-in-a-string-python) and to [Find out how many times a regex matches in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374457/find-out-how-many-times-a-regex-matches-in-a-string-in-python)

I want to count all alphabet characters in the string:

```
'Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...'
```

The `str.count()` method allows for counting a specific letter.  How would one do that for counting any letter in the entire alphabet in a string, using the count method?

I am trying to use a regex inside the count method, but it returns 0 instead of 83.  The code I am using is:

```
import re

spam_data['text'][0].count((r'[a-zA-Z]'))
```

When I use:

`len(re.findall((r'[a-zA-Z]'), spam_data['text'][0]))` it returns a length of 83.

Why does count return a 0 here?

Comment: `r'..'` is **not** a regex, it is a *raw* string.

Comment: the `count()` doesn't accept `regex`, it accepts it as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) instead of count.

```
spam_data['text'].str.count('\w')

0    83
Name: text, dtype: int64
```

To access the first value use:

```
spam_data['text'].str.count('\w')[0]
83
```

Comment: Do you know why .`str.count('\w')` works for spam_data['text'].str.count('\w) (i.e.) a dataframe column, but not for an indexed  Series created from spam_data['text']?

Comment: It's not clear what you meant here. Maybe an example code to state the issue?

Comment: Hi @Abhi, if it's possible to look here I'd be grateful! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026049/when-does-str-count-w-work-and-when-doesnt-it?noredirect=1#comment92953894_53026049

Answer (score 2):

> How would one do that for counting any letter in the entire alphabet in a string, using the count method?

```
wrd = 'Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...'
>>>> count = sum([''.join({_ for _ in wrd if _.isalpha()}).count(w) for w in wrd])
>>>> count
83
```

explanation: get the sum of unique letters count (inside a `set`) in the `wrd` using list comprehension.
similar to:

```
count = []
set_w = set()
for w in wrd:
    if w.isalpha():
        set_w.add(w)

for w in set_w:
    count.append(wrd.count(w))

print(sum(count))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: you did *not* use a regex, but a [raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals), and thus count occurrences of the string `'[a-zA-Z]`.

Because a string of the format `r'..'` is *not* a regex, it is a *raw* string *literal*. If you write `r'\n'`, you write a string with *two* characters: a backslash and an `n`. *not* a new line. Raw strings are useful in the context of regexes, because regexes use a lot of escaping as well.

For example:

```
>>> r'\n'
'\\n'
>>> type(r'\n')
<class 'str'>
```

But here you thus count the number of times the *string* `'[a-zA-Z]'` occurs, and unless your `spam_data['text'][0]` literally contains a square bracket `[` followed by `a`, etc., the count will be zero. Or as specified in the documentation of [**str.count** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count):

> **`string.count(s, sub[, start[, end]])`**
>
> Return the number of (non-overlapping) occurrences of **substring** `sub` in string `s[start:end]`. Defaults for `start` and `end` and interpretation of negative values are the same as for slices.)

In case the string is rather large, and you do not want to construct a list of matches, you can count the number of elements with:

```
sum(1 for _ in re.finditer('[a-zA-Z]', 'mystring'))
```

It is however typically faster to simply use `re.findall(..)` and then calculate the number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

In this one:

```
spam_data['text'][0].count((r'[a-zA-Z]'))
```

the `count` accepts parameter by string, **not regex**, that is why it returns 0.

Use your second example.

Comment: Then why does it return `1` for `'[a]'.count(r'[a]')`?

Comment: but now your answer seems to suggest that because the item to count is not a regex, it will always return `0`.

Comment: Or if it contains raw string like the *regex* in count firts parameter, e.g. `'a in [a]'.count(r'[a]')` => `1`