# When does .str.count('\w') work and when doesn't it?

Tags: python, pandas, count

This is a follow up question to [Regex inside findall vs regex inside count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882843/regex-inside-findall-vs-regex-inside-count/52883329#52883329)

`.str.count('\w')` works for me when called on the column of a dataframe, but not when called on a Series.

`X_train[0:7]` is a Series:

`872                       I'll text you when I drop x off
 831     Hi mate its RV did u hav a nice hol just a mes...
 1273    network operator. The service is free. For T &...
 3314    FREE MESSAGE Activate your 500 FREE Text Messa...
 4929    Hi, the SEXYCHAT girls are waiting for you to ...
 4249                              How much for an eighth?
 3640    You can stop further club tones by replying \S...
 Name: text, dtype: object`

`X_train[0:7].str.count('\w')`
returns

`872     0
 831     0
 1273    0
 3314    0
 4929    0
 4249    0
 3640    1
 Name: text, dtype: int64)`

When called on the same Series, converted into a dataframe column:

`d = X_train[0:7]`

`df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`

`df['col1'].str.count('\w')` returns:

`872      23
831     101
1273     50
3314    120
4929     98
4249     18
3640     98
Name: col1, dtype: int64`

Why does it work on a dataframe column, but not on a series?  Grateful for your advice.

Comment: Works also an `Series` for me

Comment: I'm using a Jupyter notebook and definitely getting the results I posted.  "return type(X_train[0:7]), X_train[0:7].str.count('/w')" gives me the confirmation it is a series, plus the results above